# Mutliple Modals in same page Vuejs 2

Tags: modal-dialog, vuejs2

I'm a newbie in Vuejs (i'm learning).
I'm trying to do many modals in same page using Vuejs2
Like many people, i have this console warning :

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:

I read the official doc. I understand that i'm trying to mutating a props and now with vuejs2 its no longer possible.
I tried by using data and computed methods but still doesn't work.
I know the props are now in one way and i think that i understood i need to $emit some props

Here my code:

app.js

```
Vue.component('modal', Modal);

Vue.component('modal-add-equipe', ModalContent);

Vue.component('modal-user-team', ModalContentTeamUser);
    new Vue({
        delimiters: ['${', '}'],
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            showModal: false,
            showModalAddEquipe: false,
            showModalUserTeam: false
        },
        methods: {
            openModal: function(name) {
                console.log(this.$refs[name]);
                this.$refs[name].show = true;
                //this.showModal = true;
            },
            closeModal: function(name) {
                this.$refs[name].show = false;
                //this.showModal = false;
            }
        }
    })
```

Modal.vue

```
<template>
    <transition name="modal">
        <div class="modal-mask" @click="close" v-show="show">
            <div class="modal-wrapper">
                <div class="modal-container with-border" @click.stop>
                    <slot></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    props: ['show', 'onClose'],
    methods: {
        close: function () {
            this.onClose();
        }
    },

    ready: function () {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
            if (this.show && e.keyCode == 27) {
                this.onClose();
            }
        });
    }


}

</script>
```

ModalContent.vue

```
<template>
    <modal :show.sync="show" :on-close="close">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header">
                default header
            </slot>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <slot name="body">
                default body
            </slot>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">

            </slot>
        </div>
    </modal>
</template>

<script>
var Modal = require('./Modal.vue');

export default {
    props: ['show'],
    methods: {
        close: function () {
            this.$emit('close', false);
        },
    },
    components:{
        'modal': Modal
    }
}
</script>
```

the call in twig :

```
{% for user in usersTeamed %}
<span @click="openModal('userTeam{{ user.getId() }}')"><strong>Equipes</strong></span>
    <modal-user-team ref="userTeam{{ user['id'] }}" :show.sync="showModal" @close="closeModal('userTeam{{ user['id'] }}')">
        <h3 slot="header">{{ 'equipe_modal_user_equipe'|trans }}</h3>
        <div slot="body">
            {{ form_start(formUsersTeamed[user['id']]) }}
            {{ form_rest(formUsersTeamed[user['id']]) }}
            {{ form_end(formUsersTeamed[user['id']]) }}
        </div>
    </modal-user-team>
    {% endfor %}
```

My goal it's to open one modal (but many in same page and avoid 1k variables like do the example https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html ) find by "rel"

This code is working but i have console worning !
If someone can help me please :)

PS: I use also gulp with vueify, babelify and aliasify

PS2 : Sorry for my english